# How to get redirected to a popup after Facebook login

Tags: facebook, twitter-bootstrap, django-allauth

on my django app, I have a Facebook connect button (via django allauth). When I click that, the facebook dialog box appears. Now, i want that after login, the user is redirected to a popup (bootstrap modal) with the list of friends of the user.

I have a test function for obtaining the list of friends in my views.py and it works well. What I need is that after the facbook dialog box login, it goes to this function, gets the friendlist, and return the result in a popup on the original page.

I tried setting LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/friends', which takes me to the view function and gets the friendlist, but how do I show this list in that popup? I'm using django-allauth with the bootstrap library.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*load the friends page inside a modal*

You can use the `remote` option of the modal to load the html from the friends page inside the modal. See [the docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) and look for `remote`.

Add a modal to the page where you want to show the modal:

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="myModalFriends" aria-hidden="true" data-show="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
         <h3>Friend list</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">Friend page will load here.</div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, after successful login:

```
$('#myModalFriends').modal({
    remote: '/friends'
});
```

This will load the html from your `/friends` page inside a modal.

*open a modal box the friend page loads*

If you want to show your friend list in a modal box on the friends page, you can call `$('#myModal').modal();` in document ready to show it on startup; see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/serra/n64g4/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, but its still a bit unclear to me. So, if on my homepage I have a fb connect button, i click that, the fb dialog box appears, user logs in.....now i want this to redirect to a function in my views, get the friendlist, and then open up a modal on the homepage itself.

Comment: Ah, you want to open the modal on the homepage itself ... missed that from your question. For that you can use the remote option option of the modal, which allows you to load remote html in the body of a modal. I'll see if I can post an example later.

Comment: That partially solves the problem....but if i give data-remote = '/accounts/facebook/login', Should I expect it to login, and as my redirect url is '/friends', it gets redirected there, gets friendlist and display the redirected template in the modal? Its not working right now. Does redirection work with this?

Comment: For your scenario, I don't think you should use redirection. Instead, use Javascript to open a modal after successful login. But I'm not that familiar with the login library you use.

Comment: Thanks. I think this should work, don't really know how to call a js function after successful login, looking it up now.