# Handling post back of Django all-auth in bootstrap 3 modal popup in Django App

Tags: jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, django-allauth

I am using the Django All-Auth app in my Django website with bootstrap 3 navbar template where in the Log In button is in the navbar on the top-right. The navigation is in a different file navbar.html which in turn is called by base.html

Now I am able to load the login view (account_login) of Django all-auth in the modal popup. But however on entering wrong password the user is redirected to the accounts/login url page to show the error message of Wrong Password Entry. I need to display the error messages of all-auth in the same modal popup. I have tried the following link but of no use:

[How to get redirected to a popup after Facebook login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697989/how-to-get-redirected-to-a-popup-after-facebook-login)
[Over-riding Django-allauth login/ registration urls with custom url/ pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38126241/over-riding-django-allauth-login-registration-urls-with-custom-url-pages?noredirect=1#comment67797677_38126241)
[How to POST the data from a modal form of bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508444/how-to-post-the-data-from-a-modal-form-of-bootstrap)
https://www.abidibo.net/blog/2014/05/26/how-implement-modal-popup-django-forms-bootstrap/

Please find below the code for navbar.html

```
    {% load staticfiles %}
<!-- Static navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}"><img src="{% static 'img/THM_300.png' %}" class='img-responsive' style='width:200px'/></a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">          
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
       {% if not request.user.is_authenticated %}
         <!-- Button trigger modal -->
           <li>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="{% url 'account_login' %}">
                Log In
              </button>

            </li>
        {% else %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'account_logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
        {% endif %}
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <!-- Modal content will be loaded here -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please find below the code for the login.html template of all-auth:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% load account socialaccount %}

<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Log In</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">

  <h1>{% trans "Sign In" %}</h1>

  {% get_providers as socialaccount_providers %}

  {% if socialaccount_providers %}
  <p>{% blocktrans with site.name as site_name %}Please sign in with one
  of your existing third party accounts. Or, <a href="{{ signup_url }}">sign up</a>
  for a {{ site_name }} account and sign in below:{% endblocktrans %}</p>

  <div class="socialaccount_ballot">

    <ul class="socialaccount_providers">
      {% include "socialaccount/snippets/provider_list.html" with process="login" %}
    </ul>

    <div class="login-or">{% trans 'or' %}</div>

  </div>

  {% include "socialaccount/snippets/login_extra.html" %}

  {% else %}
  <p>{% blocktrans %}If you have not created an account yet, then please
  <a href="{{ signup_url }}">sign up</a> first.{% endblocktrans %}</p>
  {% endif %}

  <form id="formlogin" class="login" method="POST" action="{% url 'account_login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    {% if redirect_field_value %}
    <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
    {% endif %}
    <a class="button secondaryAction" href="{% url 'account_reset_password' %}">{% trans "Forgot Password?" %}</a>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">{% trans "Sign In" %}</button>
  </form>

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</div>
```

Please let me know the solution properly as I am not an advanced user.

Update:
I tried using below javascript snippet but still pondering over the issue:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#formlogin').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '{% url "account_login" %}', //this is the submit URL
            type: 'POST', //or POST
            data: $('#formlogin').serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                 alert('successfully submitted');
                 $('#responsestatus').text(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure that this url {% url "account_login" %} in the last code snipped is getting converted by django? If it's in a separate js file i don't think it does, try looking where the request gets sent to. Try using url: $(this).attr('action'),

Comment: @JonasGrumann This js is in the login.html template above at the last. However the POST is itself not working; if i use GET is am able to read the response status in the modal and able to see the alert box as well. When is replace GET with POST i don't get any activity. I tried your code above as well but the ajax POST isin't happening somehow.

Comment: Can you look at the browser-debugger's network tab if the request is starting? If it is it means the problem is your Django view, if it doesn't the problem is in the frontend.

Comment: @JonasGrumann I'll check the same. However to point out I am using the default views of Django All-Auth app: http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @JonasGrumann I checked the same. When using POST the POST request is starting to the URL accounts/login of all-auth app, however it doesn't turns green and remains red.

Comment: Try to look at the server output (logs) to see if it crashes somewhere

Comment: @JonasGrumann I am using my localhost in laptop. The view most probably is not able to handle the Ajax update and return back content to be used in the modal.  Seems like I'll have to leave using Django All-Auth app.....

Comment: No I don't think that's the problem. All-Auth is definitely able to handle ajax requests. Look at the terminal window where you have your django server running, see any errors there?

Comment: @JonasGrumann Nope. No errors in terminal window.

Comment: @JonasGrumann Can you share any example code where if you've tried loading All-Auth in modal ?